# How to get my baker's delegators with specific balance?

Tags: api, tzkt

I'm not sure how to get my delegators holding greater than a 50 tez balance.

I gather I need to filter by delegate and balance.

I see filter by balance would be:

?balance.gt=1234

But not sure how to combine this to return all delegators of a baker address.

Answer (score 2):

https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Accounts_GetDelegators is the best way to do that. You just need to filter you delegators with `balance.gt=50000000`.

Here's an example:
https://api.tzkt.io/v1/accounts/tz1aRoaRhSpRYvFdyvgWLL6TGyRoGF51wDjM/delegators?balance.gt=50000000

Answer (score 1):

You can query them like this: https://api.tzkt.io/v1/accounts?delegate=tz1irJKkXS2DBWkU1NnmFQx1c1L7pbGg4yhk&balance.gt=50000000&select=address,balance,delegate&limit=10000

Here,

- `delegate=tz1irJKkXS2DBWkU1NnmFQx1c1L7pbGg4yhk` filters only those who delegate Coinbase Baker, replace the address with your own baker address.
- `balance.gt=50000000` filters only those whose balance is greater than 50 XTZ.
- `select=address,balance,delegate` only gets address, balance, and delegate info.
- `limit=10000` returns at max 10000 items in the response, this is the maximum you can set.